# How to setup the transformation function for variable change in triple integration?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble understanding the idea or what exactly goes on during the process of variable change for triple/double integration. I need someone to spell it out for me and justify the following information from an example:

We are integrating over a parallelpiped $A$ formed by $\enspace \textbf{a} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},\: \textbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\:$ and $\textbf{c} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}.$

Now they tell me that we need a function $\textbf{T}$ that takes the image of the box $D$ formed be the unit vectors: $\textbf{e}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\: \textbf{e}_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\:$ and $\textbf{e}_3 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ onto $A$, which means $\textbf{e}_1\to \textbf{a},\: \textbf{e}_2 \to \textbf{b},\: \textbf{e}_3 \to \textbf{c}$.

I.e. (and here comes the part i need explained and showed)

$$\textbf{T}(u, v, w) = (u + 2w, v + 3w, 2v + w - u).$$

So in short, if someone could explain/show me how the components in $\textbf{T}$ are derived and how to setup $\textbf{T}$ from this example i would be very greatful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a linear transformation $\mathbf{T}$, note that $u\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{e_{1}}) + v\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{e_{2}}) + w\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{e_{3}}) = \mathbf{T}(u,v,w)$

Comment: Yes i'm aware of this property of transformations, but i'm not sure how this is done in practical for this particular problem. I  need to see how this is done and get it explained in detail. I have to understand how variable changes are done in general for double/triple integrals of these kinds of regions.

Comment: You didn't specify it was a linear transformation in the question. If it is linear, map $\mathbf{e_{1}}$ to $\mathbf{a}$ by $\mathbf{T}$ to get $T(\mathbf{e_{1}}) = (1,0,-1)$, then $u\mathbf{T}(1,0,0) =  u(1,0,-1)$, repeat for $e_{2}$ and $e_{3}$ and add them.